# Java loop StackoverflowError - Any possibility to continue the previous loop when the same function is recurred again?

Tags: java, recursion

I have a program which will call a function recursively. The below program gives me `StackOverflowError`.

The output I expected is

`normal print, normal print, normal print, normal print, inside function splcase now, call action key word now, normal print, normal print, normal print, normal print, normal print`.

Is there any possibility to control the recursive function so that I get the required output?

```
public class mytest1 {

    String path, keyword;

    public static void main(String args[]){
        exec_script("normal");
    }

    public static void exec_script(String exec_path){
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            if (i==4) {
                exec_path = "spl";
            }

            switch (exec_path){
            case "spl":
                spl_case();
                break;
            case "normal":
                System.out.println("normal print");
                break;
            case "call_action_path":
                System.out.println("call action key word now");
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void spl_case(){
        System.out.println("inside function splcase now");
        exec_script("call_action_path");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

May this code helps you.

```
public class mytest1 {

    String path, keyword;

    public static void main(String args[]){
        mytest1. exec_script("normal");
    }

    public static void exec_script(String exec_path){
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
            if (i==4){
                // exec_path = "spl";
                tree("spl");
            }

            tree(exec_path);

            // switch (exec_path){
            // case "spl":
            //     spl_case();
            //     break;
            // case "normal":
            //     System.out.println("normal print");
            //     break;
            // case "call_action_path":
            //     System.out.println("call action key word now");
            //     break;
            // }
        }
    }

    public static void tree(String exec_path){
        switch (exec_path){
        case "spl":
            spl_case();
            break;
        case "normal":
            System.out.println("normal print");
            break;
        case "call_action_path":
            System.out.println("call action key word now");
            break;
        }
    }

    public static void spl_case(){
        System.out.println("inside function splcase now");
        //exec_script("call_action_path");
        tree("call_action_path");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get a stackoverflow error because your recursion goes on executing the method many times until the stack overflows.

What happens is that,after calling the method from `main`,the method calls `spl_case` in the 4th iteration and it executes the 2nd `exec_script` and then,in the 4th iteration,it calls `spl_case` and the process continues until the stack overflows.

The following program does what you want:

```
public class mytest1 {

    String path, keyword; //you have unused variables

    public static void main(String args[]){
        exec_script("normal");
    }

    public static void exec_script(String exec_path){
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            if (i==4) {
                exec_path = "spl";
            }

            switch (exec_path){
            case "spl":
                spl_case();
                System.out.println("call action key word now");
                exec_path = "normal";
                break;
            case "normal":
                System.out.println("normal print");
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void spl_case(){
        System.out.println("inside function splcase now");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get stackoverflow error because of your recursion goes on executing the method many times until the stack overflows.

You need to do following 2 modifications in your code to work

First of All, you need to Stop recursion. So, place "return" statement in following case in switch statement instead of "break" statement.

```
case "call_action_path":
            System.out.println("call action key word now");
            return;
}
```

Second Modification is,

Your modifying the "exec_path" variable value when i==4. So, exec_path variable value become "spl". So, remaining successive iterations, case "spl" will be executed because of exec_path have "spl" value. So, modify the "exec_path" variable to "normal" in following case,

```
case "spl":
    spl_case();
    exec_path = "normal";
    break;
```

So, do the following modifications and run it

Answer (score -2):

from your above it continuously going to print the iteration so use below code.

**so use below code**

```
public class mytest1 {

    String path, keyword;

    public static void main(String args[]){

        exec_script("normal");
    }
    public static void exec_script(String exec_path){
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
        if (i==4){
            exec_path = "spl";
        }

        switch (exec_path){
        case "spl":
            spl_case();
            break;
        case "normal":
            System.out.println("normal print");
            break;
        case "call_action_path":
            System.out.println("call action key word now");
            break;

        }
        return;
    }
    }

    public static void spl_case(){
        System.out.println("inside function splcase now");
        exec_script("call_action_path");
    }

}
```

Comment: If possible, explain what are the changes that you've done. Code-only answer is not really encouraged as it may confuse OP and future readers.

Comment: if we did not return the call of function it will continuously call that function so i had added return in the function to stop that execution after execution of switch case

Comment: @Ricky ,Your program just prints `normal print` and exits.